# I want excute function but it fails. do you help me?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have a function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GET_NEXT_SEQ (string code1) RETURN NUMBER 
BEGIN
    DECLARE seq_date DATE ;
    DECLARE seq_no number(8,0) ;
    DECLARE next_seq number(8,0);

    seq_date = SELECT SEQ_DATE FROM PARAM_SEQ ps WHERE SEQ_CODE = code1;
    seq_no = SELECT SEQ_NO FROM PARAM_SEQ ps WHERE SEQ_CODE = code1;

    IF seq_date = TO_DATE(sysdate,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
        BEGIN
            next_seq := seq_no + 1;
        END

        IF seq_date <> TO_DATE(sysdate,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
            BEGIN 
                next_seq := 1;
            END

            UPDATE PARAM_SEQ
            SET SEQ_DATE = TO_DATE(sysdate,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') , SEQ_NO = next_seq
            WHERE SEQ_CODE = code1;

            RETURN next_seq;
END
```

But I can't excute the function. I'm calling it like this:

```
BEGIN  
    DECLARE c NUMBER(8,0);  
    c := GET_NEXT_SEQ ('SI_TELEX_NO');  
    dbms_output.put_line('SI_TELEX_NO: ' || c);  
END;
```

Comment: this is function:

Comment: Did you ever look into the PL/SQL guide to see how to write functions in Oracle? Have a look at some sample code and you'll spot the errors in your function code, as I'm sure it does not compile. If you use sqldev to write pl/sql code like this, it will tell you where and what the errors are.

Comment: First you should get familiar with basic syntax rules of PL/SQL

Comment: Never call `TO_DATE()` on a value which is already a `DATE` (in your case `SYSDATE`)

Answer (score 2):

Your function contains so many errors:

- You cannot use declare into an object creation. Declare is for anonymous blocks.
- You don't need to format `sysdate`. it is already a date. However, as dates are stored as packets, you perhaps should reconsider to compare a string using to_char. It is not clear what you want to compare.
- You cannot perform DML inside functions if you are going to use them as part of a select statement.
- I don't know whether you want to update only when the seq_date is different of sysdate
- `string` is not generally used as data type for an input parameter in Oracle.

Anyway, an example might be

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GET_NEXT_SEQ (code1 in varchar2) RETURN NUMBER 
is
seq_date date ; 
seq_no   number(8,0) ; 
next_seq number(8,0);
begin
    SELECT SEQ_DATE , SEQ_NO into seq_date, seq_no FROM PARAM_SEQ ps WHERE SEQ_CODE = code1; 
IF seq_date = sysdate 
then 
    next_seq := seq_no + 1; 
elsif seq_date <> sysdate
then 
    next_seq := 1; 
    UPDATE PARAM_SEQ SET SEQ_DATE = sysdate , SEQ_NO = next_seq WHERE SEQ_CODE = code1;
end if;
RETURN next_seq; 
END;
/
```

Comment: Although I cannot recall anyone ever using it STRING is a valid data type in Oracle. Has been since at least v10 (maybe earlier, I never looked before that). See [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a97e345752bbbb8b64a5f2158aaa1903). It is defined in the Package STANDARD as   "subtype STRING is VARCHAR2;"

Comment: @Belayer, good to know, I had never heard of it, honestly.